# How can I combine multiple PDF files into one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

I have made my CV using Photoshop CS5.1 (3 separate files) and need to convert it to a single PDF file. I've done it before using a free download but can't remember what it was...does anybody know? Or is there another way this can be done?

Comment: Complementary info that might be helpful with your context... make sure you can select the type in the PDF of your resume as some employers use search tools to scan for specific terms when they receive a lot of applications.

Answer (score 21):

You can do it in photoshop.

From the top menu ( doesn't exist in cs6 anymore ):
**File > Automate > PDF Presentation..**

In the PDF Presentation window:

1. Select the files you want to convert to pdf.
2. Select Multi-Page Document.
3. Click Save button.

..and then the *Save abobe PDF window* comes up, where you can define the pdf settings and then save it.

[image]

If it is not that obvious, every separate file will be put in their own pages in the pdf document.

---

Another way to do this would be in **Adobe Acrobat Pro**.

To combine multiple files into one pdf in Acrobat Pro:
**File > Combine > Merge files into single pdf**

<sub>( You can also change page locations, delete pages, add pages etc... )</sub>

Comment: I've done the same thing but the resolution is very low. While viewing the PDF document at 100%, edges of fonts as well as images is grainy and not sharp. Are there any settings that can help to enhance the resolution?

Comment: @SilentAssassin If your text is not sharp, I'd have to guess that there's either something off in your Acrobat page display settings or the text is actually a raster image. Generally I wouldn't create pdf's in photoshop unless I have to. If you can, use Indesign or Illustrator. If I'd have to, I'd use text layers and shape layers to maintain scalability in the pdf.

Comment: I don't have PDF Presentation when I go to File, and I have CS4

Comment: @Imray Adobe moved a lot of these types of features over to Bridge. Here's a video on that: https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=YARpPyiNX5M

Answer (score 2):

In OSX, you can do this with Preview.app. Open one PDF, drag another into the thumbnails panel to add additional PDF files. (FWIW, PhotoShop isn't the right tool for creating a resume)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video which will show the steps that how can combine the multiple `PDF` documents in single `PDF` file with complete data. Kernel for PDF split & Merge software also provide you PDF file split feature, with the help of this feature you can split over size `PDF` file in many parts.

**[Youtube Video available with solution.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLd73Fo5Zco)**

The way is easy to use and support with all MS windows 8 and above versions.

**Sytya Sen**

Comment: Could you please tell about the method displayed in the video? That way, your answer is still of use in case the link to the video breaks or it's taken down. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply use Adobe Acrobat Pro that comes with the Adobe Suite/Cloud, and "insert" your pages in one document.**

To insert each pages, open your first PDF file, and then use these keys at the same time:

**Command + Shift + I**

A window will open and you can select all your files you want to insert.

You can also change the order of these pages by opening the "page thumbnail" panel on your left, and simply drag them where you want them. If you right-click there you will see other options, including inserting pages exactly where you want, between 2 other pages for example.

**If you need to lower the file size of your PDF after doing this, you can have a look [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49315/file-size-issue-when-exporting-from-word-2013-to-pdf/55355#55355).**

[image: How to insert multiple pages in one PDF]